# Google Drive changes history

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I get a history of all drive changes from specified point in time (lets say from last day)?

[Reports API - Drive Activity Reports](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive) seems to be the best, but these apply only to [Google Apps Unlimited accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6034782?hl=en).

I know that, it can be done also with [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push), but I'm looking for other methods, so I could choose the best one.

I have tried [Drive.Changes.List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list) but it returns only one instance of `Change` for each file, so if I edit file at time t1, and at time t2 and then I list all changes, it will return only `last change of file` (t2).

I have read something about `revisions` which can be listed, so theoretically, I would be able to get all changes (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there any other way?

Comment: +1 for actually doing your own research.  but you have already listed all of the ways you can do this, asking which is the best is only going to get you opinion based answers.  Try testing things on your own see which one is the best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes and Revisions are different things for different purposes.

To answer "**How can I get a history of all drive changes from specified point in time (lets say from last day)?**" you probably need a combination of both.

1. Not knowing your use case, my approach would be get a list of all files (file.list) with q='modifiedDate > iso'. This is more or less equivalent to a list of changes after the change ID of that point in time.
2. Then for each file, you can do revisions.list to get all of the revisions. If you want to derive the change (ie. the difference between two revisions, you'll need to do that yourself.)
3. Again, depending on what information you're looking for, the Activities API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list might be what you're looking for. So you would call that for each fileID from step 1.

NB. At step 1, use "fields" to trim your output to nextPageToken, items/id and items/modifiedDate or you'll drown in data.

As an alternative to step 1, you could have some kind of cron job that does an hourly about.get to fetch, timestamp and store the current ChangeID somewhere. Step 1 then becomes, fetch the appropriate changeId for the timestamp in question, then list changes > that changeID.

Comment: thanks for the another method, i'm just testing activities api, it looks promising.